# Hide/Unhide Last Written Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in VBA. I'd like to hide unhide all the rows from any row to the end of the sheet.
The problem I have it is I dont know how to program to hide from the last written row.
I use the next function to know the last cell written, but I dont know where to put in the Hide Function.

```
last = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
```

thanks a lot, any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this will look for the last value in colA and put all the rows from A1 until LastRow as hidden.

```
Sub test()

   'Hides all rows with data
   LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Range("A1:A" & LastRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True 'to unhide set to False

   'Hides last row until the end of the sheet
   LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   Range("B" & LastRow + 1 & ":B1048576").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'to unhide set to False

   'Hides last row + 1 until the end of the sheet
   LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   Range("B" & LastRow + 1 & ":B1048576").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'to unhide set to False

End Sub
```

**Extra info on the code**

Let's say we have data from A1 until A10

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'we use this to get the lastrow number, in this case it will be 10
'the code is variable, so if we add data until A15, lastrow will become 15

Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
'this is the range that will be hidden A1 until A10
```

Comment: It works really good, but the problem is that I want to hide from the last written cell --> to the last cell on the sheet, but this code hide, like you said, from the cell A1 --> to the last written. I don't understand the "code" "A1:A", how does it work?

Comment: Oh my bad, you want it the other way around? So lets say A10 is the last row, you want to hide row A10 until the end?

Comment: This does not include the last row if it is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You could;

```
Dim startRow As Long: startRow = 10
Dim lastRow  As Long: lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

ActiveSheet.Rows(startRow & ":" & lastRow).Hidden = True
```

Comment: This does not include the last row if it is hidden